# Como colocar um tempo de espera para o código executar?

Tags: java, android-studio, timer

Estou fazendo um joguinho da memória, mais como aprendizado em Java mesmo. Vou apresentar o código e depois explico a pergunta.

```
 private void testar (ImageView img, int resultado1, int resultado2) {

    if(resultado1 != resultado2 && resultado2 != 12){
        teste.setText("diferente");
        //quero colocar um temporizador aqui!!!
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.cartatras);

        if (flag == 1){
            carta1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cartatras);
        } else if (flag == 2) {
            carta2.setImageResource(R.drawable.cartatras);
        } else if (flag == 3) {
            carta3.setImageResource(R.drawable.cartatras);
```

Basicamente é uma função que eu fiz que compara a primeira e a segunda carta escolhida pelo usuário, e se for diferente, ele seta a carta virada nas duas escolhidas pelo usuário.

O problema é o seguinte, eu chamo esse método no `OnClick` a partir do momento em que a segunda carta é escolhida, mas não dá nem tempo de ver qual era a segunda carta, ele já seta ela como `cartatras` e o usuário não tem tempo de ver qual carta que era.

Então eu preciso de alguma forma de fazer o código esperar um pouco, para primeiro o usuário ver qual era a carta, e depois setar ela virada pra baixo. Tentei usar o `Thread.sleep` num `try`/`catch`, mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se um timer seria a melhor opção, talvez aguardar o click do usuário seria mais usual, mas enfim. Acredito que o método postDelayed da classe Handler possa te ajudar: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable,%20long)

```
handler = new Handler();

// tarefa postergada por 5000 milissegundos
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        fazAlgumaCoisa();
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza o TimeUnit
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
```

No parâmetro é só colocar quantos segundos deve ser esperado para executar uma próxima ação.